# Can I use two different versions of backbone.js in the same page?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

Can I use two different versions of backbone.js in the same page?
How about require.js? Dust.js?marionette? other JS FWs?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Use `noConflict` to make different namespaces for each version of Backbone.js you load.

http://backbonejs.org/#Utility-noConflict

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the framework.

Backbone? Yes.
jQuery? Yes.

Dust.js? No.

What you'll have to do is look at the documentation for each project to find out, but that doesn't necessarily answer the question of why you'd want to do that.